# Browser requests stopping in weird places

Tags: windows-7, networking, browser

When I make web requests in any browser to a page that might have a lot of JavaScript references it seems like it'll get through them all or the last one and stop processing the page.  I have to go to the address bar and hit enter again to load the page.  This doesn't consistently happen.  It seems like it goes through all JS files and stop at the last one and if I let it go it'll eventually (after a couple of minutes) stop trying and just stop.

I'm currently running Windows 7 RTM x64 (from MSDN).

Comment: I get this as well, though I have no idea what is causing it

Comment: any example sites of where this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using and can you try a different one?

Also, you may want to check any Firewall / IDS and temporarily disable it. I recently fixed a problem where Norton Internet Security was blocking sites in the same way as you say and it turned out to be part of the program blocking it.

Comment: I've tried IE8, Firefox 3.5, Chrome 3.0, Safari 4.  I have no software firewall and hardware firewall is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a [MTU](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/695) issue to me.

First do a

```
ipconfig
```

and remember the value behind MTU, e.g. 1500.

Subtract 28, e.g. 1500-18=1472.

Use that value and try

```
ping -f -l 1472 www.google.com
```

if it says "packet needs to be fragmented" that's it.

Comment: +1 for MTU. I've seen issues just like this that turned out to be MTU related. Are you running firewalls that block ICMP? If so, try allowing all ICMP pass through, as ICMP is required for MTU negotiation.

Comment: Edit: Just read your comment about no firewall against Wil's post, so disregard my comments about ICMP blocking. Still agree with Ludwig's answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I get similar hang-ups that mostly appear to be due to third-party-site requests.

Eg, when I load a page from `superuser.com`, the browser also requests files from `sstatic.net`, `ajax.googleapis.com`, `www.gravatar.com`, `www.google-analytics.com` and `edge.quantserve.com`.   Sometimes the browser "hangs" trying to access google-analytics.com, and the page won't finish loading until it times out, or I force a reload.

A temporary routing problem between me and any of those other servers can look like a browser hang.  Reloading the page forces the browser to reconnect to all those sites, so whatever the issue was may go away on reconnection.

Root cause could certainly be MTU-related, as Ludwig suggests, but I don't think that's the only trouble that would cause the symptom.